# I want to print the entry text from textbox to console. Below is my code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI using python tkinter.
I want to print the entry text from textbox to console after the analyzebutton is pressed. 
here is my code

```
root = Tk()

root.title('Title')

MiddleFrame = Frame(root)
BottomFrame = Frame(root)

TopFrame.pack(side = TOP)
MiddleFrame.pack()
BottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)



TextArea = Text()
ScrollBar = Scrollbar(root)
ScrollBar.config(command = TextArea.yview)
TextArea.config(height = 25, width = 70, 
background = "white", yscrollcommand = ScrollBar.set)
TextArea.grid(padx = 18, pady = 18)
ScrollBar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
padx = 10
pady = 10
TextArea.pack(padx = padx, pady = pady)


AnalyzeButton = Button(BottomFrame, text = "Analyze", fg = "white", bg = "blue", command = callback)
AnalyzeButton.pack(fill = X, padx = padx, pady = pady)

def callback():
text_input = Text.get()
print(text_input)

root.mainloop()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So, what is your problem? You need to give us more details of your situation.

Comment: There are no definitions for callback or TopFrame in here. Please read [MCVE] and [Ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use get method of Text. Use the widget not the class-Text. Here is what you need to do:-

```
text_input = TextArea.get("1.0","end-1c")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code. I will break it down so you understand what is going on here.

Fist I noticed you have tried to pack `TopFrame` but you have not actually defined `TopFrame` yet. So I added `TopFrame = Frame(root)` to your code.

Next we have a common mistake people encounter when trying to use `grid()` and `pack()` on the same window/frame. This is not allowed by the geometry manager. So you will need to decide on either `grid()` or `pack()` for all your needs in each window/frame. For now I changed `TextArea.grid()` to `TextArea.pack()` to get your code to work.

Next your button command was referencing a function that was after the command. This does not work outside of a class so you will need to move your `callback()` function above your `AnalyzeButton`.

Next we need to fix the indention on your `callback()` function. You must remember indention is very important in python and you should take care to keep your indention clean and consistent.

The last thing we needed to fix to get everything working as you were intending is to change:

`text_input = Text.get()`

To:

`text_input = TextArea.get(1.0, END)`

You were trying to call `get()` on the method that created the text widget and not the widget instance.

You also need to define from what part of the text widget you want to start reading data and how far you want to read through the text widget. this is done by applying 2 positions points with `1.0, END` or `"1.0", "end-1c"` as tkinter allows for a few ways to apply these points. This will say `1.0` start at the first line at the first position on that line and `END` will say read until the last line of the textbox.

There may be other issues but I only fixed the problems preventing the code from working as intended. Your code modified to work below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('Title')

TopFrame = Frame(root) # was missing from your code
MiddleFrame = Frame(root)
BottomFrame = Frame(root)

TopFrame.pack(side = TOP)
MiddleFrame.pack()
BottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)

TextArea = Text()
ScrollBar = Scrollbar(root)
ScrollBar.config(command = TextArea.yview)
TextArea.config(height = 25, width = 70, 
background = "white", yscrollcommand = ScrollBar.set)
TextArea.pack() # can't use pack and grid on the same window/frame. Changed this to pack()
ScrollBar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
padx = 10
pady = 10
TextArea.pack(padx = padx, pady = pady)

# this function needs to be before the command that references it.
def callback():
    # fixed indention
    text_input = TextArea.get(1.0, END) # you need to reference that widget name not the tkinter method used to create the widget.
    print(text_input)

AnalyzeButton = Button(BottomFrame, text = "Analyze", fg = "white", bg = "blue", command = callback)
AnalyzeButton.pack(fill = X, padx = padx, pady = pady)

root.mainloop()
```